# Using different production and staging requirements files on dotcloud

Tags: deployment, dotcloud

I am trying to use a prebuild hook to install separate requirements for a Django project in  development and production on Dotcloud (really just a couple of debug packages left out in production).  I'm defining a DEBUG environment variable to trigger debug behavior, and I'd like to choose a pip requirements file.  I wanted to use the prebuild hook to run a Python script that checks the value of the debug variable and symlinks the correct requirements file to `requirements.txt` in the root directory, but this does not seem to be working.  As far as I can tell, the prebuild hook isn't even running, and I'm using `dotcloud push --clean` to attempt to force a clean installation.  Am I misunderstanding how the prebuild hook works?  If it's not a good way to use variable requirements, what else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel rather dumb, but I do want to leave my question up because the method works.  My problem was a faulty `dotcloud.yml` file, in which my indentation included `prebuild` under `config`, instead of directly under the service name.

If anyone else wants to do this, here's a structure that works for me:

*dotcloud.yml*

```
www:
  type: python
  prebuild: python dotcloud/prebuild.py
  config:
    python_version: v2.7

... and so on ...
```

*dotcloud/prebuild.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import os

with open('/home/dotcloud/environment.json') as f:
    env = json.load(f)

try:
    os.unlink('requirements.txt')
except OSError:
    pass

if str(env.get('DEBUG', False)).lower() in ['t', 'true', 'y', 'yes', 'on']:
    print 'Using DEBUG mode requirements'
    os.symlink('requirements/dotcloud_debug.txt', 'requirements.txt')
else:
    print 'Using PRODUCTION mode requirements'
    os.symlink('requirements/dotcloud_production.txt', 'requirements.txt')
```